# from string to date PowerShell

Tags: powershell, date, format

I am quite new in coding. Here's is the point I have an issue in PowerShell.

I get a variable from a csv which I called `$datefinder = (Get-Date -Format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")`

I get the right answer for this variable in my loop, but the in the same loop I need my variable $datefinder with 30 more days.

I've tried to create a new variable like:

```
$2ndeDate = $datefinder.adddays(+30)
```

My variable datefinder is a string so I need to pass it into date. I've tried many things.

Here is the first line of the csv file

```
UCB63_DATENUM;U6618_FILENAME;UF6E8_CANAL;U65B8_IDRP
7/8/19 22:27;457E6659_ZN_LIQRLVPR_A_V_ML.pdf;ML;1367091
```

Comment: The format of the date in your example is **not** what you described.. In the CSV it is formatted `M/d/yy HH:mm` or `d/M/yy HH:mm`. Please find a better example csv line where it is clear if the Month or the day comes first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always a good idea to use date variables as real [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime) objects. Only when you need these formatted for some reason, you turn them into strings in a certain format.

Luckily the reverse is also possible.
According to the example you just gave, you need to parse the date from the CSV either like this:

```
$datefinder = [datetime]::ParseExact('7/8/19 19:18', 'M/d/yy HH:mm', $null)
# gets you the date Monday, July 8 2019 19:18:00
```

or like this:

```
$datefinder = [datetime]::ParseExact('7/8/19 19:18', 'd/M/yy HH:mm', $null)
# gets you the date Wednesday, August 7 2019 19:18:00
```

Having this date as DateTime object, you can use its method `AddDays()` to add a number of days:

```
$2ndDate = $datefinder.AddDays(30)  # 30 days in the future as of the date in $datefinder
```

or

```
$2ndDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)  # 30 days in the past
```

Hope that helps somewhat

Comment: the thing is i need to update the date finder (+30) 
this solution $2ndDate = $datefinder.AddDays(30) didn't work because it is see as a string

Comment: I got the date from the variable   ;   $datefinder = (Get-Date -Format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")   and the result is a string. As you can see the date comes from the csv, (sorry badly fromated) in this case 7/8/19 22:27.

Comment: @HadrienBeaujean Yes, because in that line you explicitely **convert it** to a string with the `-Format` operator. If you want it to be a DateTime object, just do `$datefinder = Get-Date`

Comment: I've also tried the parse method but maybe i made a mistake in the syntax

Comment: @HadrienBeaujean I have edited the answer to get a datetime object from the (string) date in the CSV. Because the example isn't clear enough, the format could be `'M/d/yy HH:mm'` or `'d/M/yy HH:mm'`. I've put in parsing methods for both variations.

Comment: but i don't get the right format at the end and i need it in a different format in order to build my xml the way i want

Comment: @HadrienBeaujean So, what format do you need it to be?

Comment: now i get the date with the format     jeudi 2 juillet 2020 20:12:01 and i need it like dd/MM/yyyy for both variables

Comment: @HadrienBeaujean Then if you need the dates back as formatted strings, you can do `Get-Date $datefinder -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy'` or `$datefinder.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy')` or `'{0:dd/MM/yyyy}' -f $datefinder` (these are all different ways of doing exactly the same thing)

Comment: You are the best!!!!!!!! This is perfect!!! Thanx a lot